# code 100 while installing tensorflow serving

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to install tensorflow serving in ubuntu via a docker image

I have cloned the tensorflow serving repo from "https://github.com/tensorflow/serving" and trying to create a docker image with the help of below command:

```
docker build --pull -t $USER/tensorflow-serving-devel -f tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel .
```

When i tried to do, I am getting the following error:

```
Reading package lists...
W: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/universe/source/Sources  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) Error writing to file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/source/Sources  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) Error writing to file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/source/Sources  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) Error writing to file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) Error writing to file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y         build-essential         curl         git         libfreetype6-dev         libpng12-dev         libzmq3-dev         mlocate         pkg-config         python-dev         python-numpy         python-pip         software-properties-common         swig         zip         zlib1g-dev         libcurl3-dev         openjdk-8-jdk        openjdk-8-jre-headless         wget         &&     apt-get clean &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Is that Ubuntu Xenial version doesnt have a release for Tensorflow serving? Or is it that i am missing out something?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Read through this link.
https://hub.docker.com/r/yesuprelease/tensorflow-serving-devel/ .
It looks like Ubuntu 16.04 has a release for tensorflow serving. Mostly it's a problem of less memory space in your system that led to failed fetching.